# The project file <path>.csproj was not found when building c#application in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have an issue where I have one file location for class libraries and one file location for my main projects.

One of the references class libraries causes an error (only in one specific project) when building:

```
..\..\..\..\..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\API_Libraries\Unified_MarketInformation_Helper_Library\Unified_MarketInformation_Helper_Library.csproj" was not found.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   1773
```

The [Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/additional-msbuild-resources?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(MSBuild.MSBuild.ProjectFileNotFound)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2015) to this error seems to be an empty page..

I have found a workaround which I do not fully understand the cause and will brake my code on other devices where my username is different:

Project file old:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\API_Libraries\Unified_MarketInformation_Helper_Library\Unified_MarketInformation_Helper_Library.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\CSV_Helper_Project\CSV_Helper_Project\CSV_Helper_Project.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\String_Helper_Project\String_Helper_Project\String_Helper_Project.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Project file with "workaround" (note the base path is hardcoded for the first referenced library, the other libraries are working fine):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="C:\Users\julia\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\API_Libraries\Unified_MarketInformation_Helper_Library\Unified_MarketInformation_Helper_Library.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\CSV_Helper_Project\CSV_Helper_Project\CSV_Helper_Project.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\String_Helper_Project\String_Helper_Project\String_Helper_Project.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What could be causing this issue?
Is there a proper fix which will not break the reference on other machine with a different username?

Comment: The best solution: stop using OneDrive as a code repository. Use a normal, non-OneDrive path and use something like the free GitHub tier to share the code

Comment: Maybe path is too long?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I did some tests and created the same file path as you to reproduce the problem:
[image]

Most likely this error is generated because of a relative path error.

You can change the project file like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\API_Libraries\Unified_MarketInformation_Helper_Library\Unified_MarketInformation_Helper_Library.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\CSV_Helper_Project\CSV_Helper_Project\CSV_Helper_Project.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\OneDrive\Projects\Libraries\String_Helper_Project\String_Helper_Project\String_Helper_Project.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This worked for me in my test, the project builds successfully after changing the relative path.
[image]